# Spring 3 MVC: is it possible to have a spring form without 'commandName' binding?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

My question is, Is it necessary to have a '*commandName*' binding for forms and '*path*' bindings for inputs?

I have a work flow which needs users to select data from a series of ajaxy select boxes. So the form doesn't exactly map to any model directly. It seems rather pointless to add another model just to accommodate this form, while everything on this form will be driven by ajax. 
Now I know I can always write a classic form and select tags, but I would like to take advantage of spring tags here for example:

```
<form:options items="${list}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="id"/>
```

which allows me to easily populate by form items. And plus I would like to maintain uniformity in the project and use spring tags through.

I would like to know thoughts and opinions on this topic.

Thanks!

PS: I am coming from ruby on rails background and am used to lot of syntactic sugar :P forgive me if the question sounds silly or answer obvious.

Comment: `<form:options>` is a Spring tag. It has nothing to do with the JSTL.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know if it's useful, but here it goes:

If you don't set a 'commandName' in the form, the default value for this property will be set as 'command'. So, if you don't set it, the bound data will have the name 'command'.

If you want, you can set it with the name of your bound data.

==========================================================================

**A solution without using data binding would be:**

I would add a HttpServletRequest request parameter to the controller method and get the parameter like servlets do.

```
@Controller 
public class SomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/formAction", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String controllerMethod(HttpServletRequest request){  
        // this way you get value of the input you want
        String pathValue1 = request.getParameter("path1");
        String pathValue2 = request.getParameter("path2");
        return "successfulView";
    }

}
```

PS.: the 'path1' and 'path2' are the path names you set in the inputs.
I know it seems do not use the Spring properly, but its a hack that Spring let us to use.

The form would be this way:

```
<form:form method="post" action="/formAction">
    <form:input path="path1" />
    <form:input path="path2" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form:form>
```

Hope its useful.

Comment: Right, but then what happens with the 'path' elements in its input variables?? I mean they are suppose to be properties of 'commandName' right.

Comment: I didn't understand very well, but I know that 'commandName' is only to indicate the name of the object you're binding to your form. After testing the 'path' property I found that it is extremely necessary. You have to put the name of the Class attribute of your bound object.
You do not really have to put path="commandName.attributeName". If you're binding only one object you can only put path="attributeName".
Summarizing, you have to put always the 'path' name in your inputs,but not really in 'commandName'.

Comment: well that's the reason for my questions. I dont need any bindings any where! I just need a set of inputs populated with spring. So is there a way to do this by sticking to spring tags.

Comment: Oh, now I got what is your question. Well, I don't really know the exact answer to this but I would do like the next answer. (I will update this answer)

Comment: Can you please update how the actual form tags and input will look like in this case?? because, correct me if i am wrong, but doesnt spring validate the presence of a valid 'commandName' and 'path's when the jsp is first rendered? In the example you have given it makes sense that paths are being used as keys to retrieve the parameters in the controller once the form is submitted. How to make the form tag and its inputs compile successfully? or am i missing something?

Comment: Well, you don't really have to set a 'commandName'. If you don't set, the default value for 'commandName' will be 'command'. So, when you render the form you can bind a object or not. If bind a object (with model attribute) you have to set a new 'commandName' or use the 'command' value for it. In our case here, we don't need to set 'commandName'...This way, we use the HttpServletRequest to handle the request parameters, using the 'path' as a key to get the values, just the way you said.
What kind of error are you having?

Answer (score 7):

If we are not adding the commandName to spring form tags an exception willl be raised as
IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object "command" available as request parameter...

Comment: Solution is not use a Spring form.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697143/spring-form-without-commandname