# Spring form without commandName

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring, and I have a problem. I have a form which is used to send information to the controller. I don't need or want to have a bean backing up the form so I left the `commandName` attribute in the form blank like this:

```
<form:form action="getReportFile.html" method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="field1">Field1:</form:label></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:select path="field1" items="${FieldMap}" />                        
                    </td>
                </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td><form:label path="field2">Field2:</form:label></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td><form:input path="field2"/></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
               </tr>
           </table>
       </form:form>
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute
```

I could see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651769/spring-3-mvc-is-it-possible-to-have-a-spring-form-without-commandname-binding) that when you don't give a value to `commandName` it uses the default `'command'`, but then, **Do I have to configure anything else? should I put a `'command'` bean in the `dispatcher-servlet.xml`? How would that bean?**

I just want a form to send the information to the controller. **Do I really have to create a bean to back it?**

Comment: Well, actually the other question is a duplicate of this, as this one was asked before :) @SotiriosDelimanolis

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't need a command object at all, then avoid the Spring form and simply use an HTML form.

So, change

```
<form:form action="getReportFile.html" method="post">
     .
     .
     .
</form:form>
```

to

```
<form action="getReportFile.html" method="post">
     .
     .
     .
</form>
```

The command object is indeed not mandatory. It is mandatory only if you use the Spring's form like `<form:form></form:form>` using the following library.

```
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
```

You have to receive the request parameters using the `request.getParameter("paramName")` method, if you use an HTML form.

---

> if you don't have a form backing bean, you can't use the Spring
>    tag since it does require one! Your "path" attribute on
>   that tag is supposed to specify the path to the model bean's property
>   for data binding.

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?83532-how-to-have-form-without-command-object&p=279807#post279807

Comment: You're welcome. If you need server side validation using something like `HibernateValidator`, then you must have a backing bean as described by @jfrank in his answer. Once upon a time, it was also my requirement to avoid a backing bean (a backing bean was indeed not required because everything on a JSP page was handled only by the Spring JSON).

Comment: so simple yet apparently so uncommon. Every tutorial uses form:form, which brings a lot of binding baggage that isn't often explained. I don't think it's uncommon to want a form that doesn't relate to a model (a search form, a contact form for example) yet almost no tutorial covers it.

Comment: @Lion, Hi, I am using the normal **HTML Form** and using an input tag like `<input type="text" name="someInput" />`. But my request.getParameter("someInput") always returns null. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it's possible to make a form with no backing bean in Spring MVC, but I think you won't get much out of Spring MVC without using a bean.  Those form tags you are using (like form:input) get bound to properties of the backing bean, and this lets you attach things like validation, error messages, type conversion, etc.  Is your intent simply to post the form to a Spring controller, and handle all the form fields on the server with code like "request.getParameter('field1')"?  Then I would suggest just using a plain HTML form.