# Is it mandatory to use commandName attribute in spring form?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Here is my form

```
<form:form name="UserRegistrationForm" id="UserRegistrationForm" method="post" action="user" commandName="userData" autocomplete="off">
.....
</form:form>
```

Here is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showUserPage(Model model, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpSession session, Locale locale) throws HCException {
model.addAttribute("userData",userData);
        return "home/userHome";
    }
```

I get below error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141) ~[spring-webmvc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
```

If i add `commandName="userData`" attribute in form tag, it works fine

**Is it mandatory to use commandName attribute in spring form ?**

As per my understanding commandName attribute is only required if developer has set something under modelAttribute(say userData) in controller 
and want to access its properties without prefix userData. For example if userData contains email field, developer can directly use email under path `if commandName = "userData" is specified in form tag`
otherwise he can user EL i.e $userData.email . So why spring expecting commandName attribute here ?

Answer (score 0):

No.

It has a default value, which is "command".

If in your controller, you can set the name of your "main" form attribute:

```
model.addAttribute("command", foo);
```

But I would argue that it's better to explicitly name the model attribute and form attribute something reflecting the type of the object, in your case "userData".

Comment: what if i want to set model.addAttribute("userData", foo) in my controller  and use it thru Expression language 
(without using attribute commandName = "userData")?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use commandName to spring form tags otherwise you will get below exception . This happens when you use spring tags for html elements
IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object "command" available as request parameter...

see [Spring 3 MVC: is it possible to have a spring form without 'commandName' binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651769/spring-3-mvc-is-it-possible-to-have-a-spring-form-without-commandname-binding) also